# Is Proguard necessary for gradle 3.2.1?

Tags: android, proguard, facebook-android-sdk

I am doing this first time. Using Facebook SDK for android app. 
I am following this tutorial. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/

My app is gradle 3.2.1
Do I need to use ProGuard here? 
What code should I write between the given two codes on this link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html?fbclid=IwAR3hmG6hOtzfyiHa3Sehxa4o2j9vq9sPrk8ZVbr-WWyUDakiskFMZQgloJM

android {

```
buildTypes {

    release {

        // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
        // your project's release build type.

        minifyEnabled true

        // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
        // Android Gradle plugin.

        shrinkResources true

        // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
        // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
        // R8 configuration files.

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}

...
```

}

And another code:

android {
    ...

```
buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
          'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),

          // List additional ProGuard rules for the given build type here. By default,
          // Android Studio creates and includes an empty rules file for you (located
          // at the root directory of each module).
          'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {

    flavor1 {

      ...
    }
    flavor2 {

        proguardFile 'flavor2-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

There are some more small codes below it, which one should I add? 
Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

As you add ProGuard files you have to add this

```
        useProguard true
```

in your gradle File(module)

Comment: But, which code should I write between the two shared in the question?